# Como puedo obtener los datos a través del id en mysql

Tags: mysql

Como puedo hacer una consulta que a través del id me muestre todos los datos de la persona en mysql.
Quiero verificar que el id_emisor sea la persona que e ingresado en la tabla persona.

Hice este intento:

```
Select NOMBRES from altas where id_emisor = idPersona;
```

Y me bota errores, ya están relacionadas como `foreign key`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir las pruebas que hayas hecho?

Comment: Hola Jose. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Como dice @marc has de mostrar lo intentado para sobre eso explicarte que tienes mal y como mejorarlo, en vez de hacertelo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta.  Un saludo

Comment: Puedes añadir los errores que dices que te da al hacer la consulta?

Comment: ¿esa consulta la estas haciendo directo en consola o utilizando php?

Comment: Directo desde phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en si deberías de llamar la FK de la tabla que relacionas igual, por convención, pero para darte una solución a tu consulta te da error porque no indicas a que tabla pertenece que campo en la query por eso al no saber de donde obtener los datos te da error, deberias hacer la query de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT nombres FROM personas INNER JOIN altas ON personas.id_persona = altas.id_emisor;
```

suponiendo que cambies la estructura de la tabla y tengas una FK que se llame id_persona se puede simplificar aún más asi:

```
SELECT nombres FROM personas
JOIN altas USING(id_persona);
```

toma en cuenta que en ambas tablas debes tener el mismo campo con el mismo nombre, mismo tipo y misma longitud y obviamente su FK que los relacione, para que este ultimo ejemplo te funcione correctamente; espero te sirva...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from personas , altas  
where altas.ID_EMISOR = personas.ID_PERSONA
```

Comment: Hola. Una respuesta que es solo codigo no se considera de buena calidad. Has de explicar qué tenia mal la pregunta y como tu respuesta lo soluciona. Mira [answer] para aprender a mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from personas p 
inner join altas a on p.id_persona = a.id_emisor
```

Comment: Hola. Una respuesta que es solo codigo no se considera de buena calidad. Has de explicar qué tenia mal la pregunta y como tu respuesta lo soluciona. Mira [answer] para aprender a mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo